# jq overwrites the unique key rather than adding to the JSON object in file

Tags: jq

### JSON File

#### Current

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "test": {
      "auth": "testserfdddd"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Desired

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "test": {
      "auth": "testserfdddd"
    },
    "myrepo.com" {
      "auth": "passworder"
    }
  }
}
```

### Tests

As a simple test on the command line I perform the following:

```bash
 cat .docker/config.json | jq '.auths += {"myrepo.com": {"auth": "passworder"}}'
```

the result is what I desire

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "test": {
      "auth": "testserfdddd"
    },
    "repo.com": {
      "auth": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

However I wish execute the same logic through a bash script.

#### Bash Script

```
REPO=repo.com
PASSWD=passworder

$JQ --arg repo "$REPO" --arg passwd "$PASSWD" '.auths.[$repo] += {"auth": $passwd}' .docker/config.json
```

This however overwrites the `test.auth` to `repo.com.auth` and does not add to the `auths` key

the result when running the bash script provides the following result

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "repo.com": {
      "auth": "passworder
    }
  }
}
```

the previous object is completely overwritten. What is generally the pattern I need to adapt here in the `jq` expression? Since the argument `repo` is unique (`test` is not the same as `repo.com`) why is the `+=` operation not working within the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQ requires the key to be put in parenthesis:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=testfile.json
REP=repo.com
PWD=passworder

cat $FILE | jq --arg repo "$REP" --arg pass "$PWD" '.auths += { ($repo) : {"auth": $pass}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using slightly simplified syntax compared to [White Owl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708145/116858):

```bash
repo=repo.com
auth=passworder

jq --arg auth "$auth" --arg repo "$repo" '.auths[$repo] = { auth: $auth }' file
```

If `auth` is the only key in the leaf object, or if the leaf object is guaranteed to not already exist:

```bash
repo=repo.com
auth=passworder

jq --arg auth "$auth" --arg repo "$repo" '.auths[$repo].auth = $auth' file
```